# Azure Notification Hub Cannot Send Push Notification to App Published for App Store

Tags: ios, azure, notifications

We have developed a service that sends push notifications to an Azure notification hub instance. These notifications are then to be sent to an APNS and pushed to registered IOS devices.

Throughout development, we have tested this working accross multiple QA Environments. We have also tested on sandbox/development versions of recieving apps ensuring the certificates in the notification hub match. All successful. We have now setup our live environment and are encountering Issues. We Archived our app through xcode and uploaded to the app store. The final app distributed internally via enterprise is recieving notifications, however the app distributed to the app store is not recieivng any notifications. This includes test sends through azure. In this case, once the message fails, the registrations are removed. We are using seperate certificates for each app Id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a resolution to our problem.

We had already created a new certificate for the app that we distributed to the IOS app store.[ the certificate was correct for environment and purpose]. This made us believe it could not be due to our certificate.

Our problem was that: just uploading the new certificate in place of the old one in azure seems to cause an issue. Azure may cache information from the previous certificate, however this is an assumption based on our resolution.

Our fix was: To completely delete the Notification service credential and create a new one from scratch, still using the certificate created for app store release.